# Canceling navigation with wpf browser

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I would like to create a stop button in my **WPF** browser but cannot find the event to assign to the button. I can only find solutions for windows forms and Iwebbrowser2 and this is not what I am searching for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where did you look for that event? You can't have tried too hard, because it is *easily* found in the most common resource for coding, MSDN. This should *always* be the first place that you look. From the [`WebBrowser.Navigating` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Occurs just before navigation to a document.
>       ...
>   Navigating event handlers are passed an instance of the NavigatingCancelEventArgs class. You can cancel the navigation by setting the Cancel property of the NavigatingCancelEventArgs object to true.

In the linked page, you'll see that it uses an object of type `NavigatingCancelEventArgs` and if you look on the [`NavigatingCancelEventArgs` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, you'll see a property named `Cancel`:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the event should be canceled. (Inherited from CancelEventArgs.)

Then if you see the [`CancelEventArgs.Cancel` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page, you'll see an example of exactly how to use it. In your case, you'd do something like this:

```
public void NavigatingCancelEventHandler(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

In future, please *actually* search for an answer and refer to the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the StackOverflow Help Center *before* posting another question.

Comment: I have several times tried to make this work with no success, I'm not ruling out that it is my own incompetence keeping me from making this happen but I simply am not able to. After adding the code you put at the end of your reply to the "click" event, do I need to add anything else since this gives me an error(no overload for 'name' matches delgate 'System.WindowsRoutedEventHandler')? 

Would really appreciate a detailed answer as I've spent many hours trying to fix this. (I'm fairly new to WPF so I'm not all that good at it yet)

Comment: Why would you try to handle a `Click` event with a `NavigatingCancelEventHandler` handler? Read the answer. It clearly says that the event you're after is the `WebBrowser.Navigating` Event. So try attaching the `NavigatingCancelEventHandler` handler to the `WebBrowser.Navigating` Event instead. As it stands, it should cancel *all* attempts to navigate to a new page.